# DELETE/PUT verbs result in 500 and 404 Not Found in WebAPI CORE on server

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am getting 500 web api error for HTTP.PUT but my GET, DELETE, and POST are working.
At first, only GET and POST were working and I was getting 404 web api error. IIS is set at Integrated and not Classic. I modified the web.conf (after reading a few posts) to the following

```
<system.webServer>
 <security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
            <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Now the 404 error is gone but 500 shows up only on server and not my VS local IIS Express for only HTTP PUT on the test server.

Here is my api PUT code

```
[HttpPut(UserObject)]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserModel>> UpdateUser([FromBody] UserUpdatedDto request)
{
   return Ok (UpdateUser(request));
}
```

I tested the api code on my local IIS Express and HTTP Put works. When deploy to the test server, only HTTP PUT is throwing an exception. I don't think it is the code from passing an populated object with many fields because HTTP POST works with ADD a record in DB. The same technique is used with UPDATE and HTTP PUT. A populated object is passed from client to api.
I am guessing its either the IIS settings or the web.config file.

I am not sure why POST and DELETE are working but why not PUT. Is there something I am missing in the webconfig?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend enabling Failed Request Tracing in IIS to check what's going on on IIS side. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/tracefailedrequestslogging

Comment: What is `UserObject` that is passed as a parameter to your `HttpPutAttribute`? Hopefully it's a string constant representing the route template. If it's not, I think something is wrong there. Seeing as your `UpdateUser()` method is synchronous, you could remove the `async Task` from the `UpdateUser` method, and run that synchronously too, if you wanted. Also, that 500 Internal Server Error could be caused by whatever happens inside the `UpdateUser` method. Did you debug that method to ensure it's not throwing an exception?